# Do I always need to wrap the component content in a div (or similar)?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm creating single file components in Vue2, and I'm including a child component:

Parent Component:

```
<template>
  <div>
     <my-component-2>
     </my-component-2>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  ....
</script>
```

Child component (my-component-2):

```
<template>
     <my-component-3>
     </my-component-3>
</template>

<script>
  ....
</script>
```

Grandchild component (my-component-3):

```
<template>
     <div v-for="(item, index) in items">
     </div>
</template>

<script>
  ...
</script>
```

But `my-component-3` is not "rendered", however if I wrap `<my-component-3>` in a div (like in the parent component calling my-component-2), then it works.

Is there a way to call a child component without wrapping it in any html tag?

Comment: This should be working: https://jsfiddle.net/dthadfp6/ What do you mean `my-component-3` is not rendered? What's in it?

Comment: @thanksd Does it work if I use "Single File Components"? That's how I'm testing it.

Comment: yeah it should work either way. What does your `my-component-3` template look like?

Comment: I see what my problem should be... there is a `v-for` in `my-component-3`.

Comment: So the answer is: No, you don't need to wrap the component in a div, but a component's template must have only a single root element. Your `my-component-3` was not displaying because it did not have a single root element.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `<template>` of a component can only have one direct child node.

Since your `my-component-3` component's root element used a `v-for`, it could not render, since it would have multiple child nodes.

You never need to wrap a component in any element when using it in another component's template.

Answer (score 0):

Example **Multiple Elements**

```js
<template>
   <template v-if="anyKey">
       <div> DIV 1 Content </div>
       <div> DIV 2 Content </div>
   </template>
</template>
export default {
    name: 'MyComponent',
    data() {
        return {
            anyKey: "Any Value"
        }
    },
 // ...
}
```

HTML will render **without wrapping element**

```html
  <div> DIV 1 Content </div>
  <div> DIV 2 Content </div>
```